# Excel/VBA: Create button that copies certain cell's content to clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have one button per row that copies the content of a cell of that particular row to the clipboard.

In the example, a button in column `B` should, when pressed, copy the content of the cell with the same row number and column `E`.

I've never used a macro in Excel, but I suppose that's what I need here?

```
   A | B   | C | D | E      | 
1|   |[BTN]|   |   |'foo'   |
2|   |[BTN]|   |   |'bar'   |
3|   |[BTN]|   |   |'foobar'|
4|   |[BTN]|   |   |        |
5|   |[BTN]|   |   |        |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add a button in each cell (in col B) with the action set to copy the content from the col E in same row :

Here is to create the buttons :

```
Sub Add_Buttons()
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim RgBtn As Range
Dim Btn As Shape

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = wS.Range("E" & wS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Set RgBtn = wS.Cells(i, 2)
    Set Btn = wS.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, _
                        RgBtn.Left, RgBtn.Top, RgBtn.Width, RgBtn.Height)

    With Btn
        .OnAction = "'CopyColE " & i & "'"
        .OLEFormat.Object.Text = "Copy test " & i
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

And the code to put the contents of col E in clipboard :

```
Public Sub CopyColE(ByVal RowIndex As Long)
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Call CopyText(wS.Range("E" & RowIndex).Value)
End Sub

Public Sub CopyText(Text As String)
    Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
    Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
    MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

And the procedure to delete all buttons previously created (to use before generating new buttons!)

```
Sub Delete_All_Buttons()
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim Btn As Shape

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each Btn In wS.Shapes
    Btn.Delete
Next Btn

End Sub
```

I've not found a way (yet, I hope) to pass the Sheet as a parameter, so for the moment, you have to define it 2 times (in `Add_Buttons` and `CopyColE`)

Comment: Great Stuff! Will try that out. But where does it say to put the buttons in column `B`? At the assignment of `LastRow`? thx

Comment: `wS.Cells(i, 2)` it the `2` ;) I just tested with the new edit it works awesomely^^

Comment: Ah I see! :) Why does `i` start at 2? In the other answer  the buttons start at row 2, maybe that's why?

Comment: Hehe, just the habit of working with headers on row 1! ;)
So just change the start of the `For` loop : `For i = 1 To LastRow`

Comment: Oh of course, could have seen that one coming, sorry =)

Comment: @tzippy : No worries, Excel is a nice tool but there is no row 0 for headers! ;)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very very much! Next I'll get into how it actually works just to understand it a bit.

Comment: @tzippy : You're welcome, copy a command (ie `AddFormControl`) and press F2 to see more! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically add a button `Shape` to a `Worksheet` and fit it to the cell dimensions and then further add an action to that button. At the time of creating the button you can add an `AlternativeText` to the button with the address of the `Range` it is fitted into. Later, in the button 'action' routine, you can retrieve the address of the `Range` so that you can manipulate cell values on the row of that button - including copying some cell value on that row to clipboard.

Sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateButtons()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim rngButton As Range
    Dim shpButton As Shape

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'ws.Cells.Delete

    'create a sequence of buttons
    For lngRow = 2 To 11
        'get a range
        Set rngButton = ws.Cells(lngRow, 2)

        'use range properties to define button boundaries
        Set shpButton = ws.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, _
            rngButton.Left, _
            rngButton.Top, _
            rngButton.Width, _
            rngButton.Height)

        'add button properties - action, caption and alt text
        With shpButton
            .OnAction = "DoButtonAction"
            .OLEFormat.Object.Text = "Foo" & lngRow
            ' store the cell address here
            .AlternativeText = rngButton.Address
        End With

        'add a value to column D to use later
        ws.Cells(lngRow, 4).Value = lngRow

    Next lngRow

End Sub

Sub DoButtonAction()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim strControlName As String
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim rngButton As Range

    'get button name
    strControlName = Application.Caller

    'get alternative text which has cell address
    strAddress = ActiveSheet.Shapes(strControlName).AlternativeText

    'get range corresponding to button and do stuff with cells in that row
    Set rngButton = ActiveSheet.Range(strAddress)

    'set a cell value on row of button
    rngButton.Offset(0, 3).Value = rngButton.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1

    'copy cell value for use later
    rngButton.Offset(0, 2).Copy

End Sub
```

In the screenshot cell `D9` value has been copied to the clipboard:

[image]